# Twitter Bootstrap 4 - where is the default style?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to start with bootstrap 4 - trying to make a form that looks like this one http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/

[image]

Mine looks like this:

[image]

Clearly the reason is because the bootstrap example file includes

```
<link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Once I copy this css in, my form looks fine.

But I am puzzled - I want my whole UI to be styled in a plain bootstrap way.  Am I missing some sort of stylesheet that is applied globally or something?  Why was there a little fragment of css in this example page?  How can I get a plain bootstrap style applied to my whole site?  It seems strange that there are examples that somehow leave me wondering how to set the style?

Comment: I downloaded their example package just now to confirm. In it there's a file

`\docs\4.0\examples\sign-in.html`

And it renders exactly the same as their live example.

Comment: @Shadetheartist thanks for your comment - not sure what you are saying though?  I'm wondering is there some sort of stylesheet I can get that styles bootstrap in some standard way?  Because the example uses its own CSS fragment which seems to suggest I need to make or find CSS fragments for every part of Bootstrap 4 which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm guessing that form was created quite a long time ago i.e. before Bootstrap 4 classes were finalized. That would be the only explanation that would make sense here. The copyright also says "© 2017-2018" there. So, must have been early 2017 or something when they created the example and then probably forgot to update it with classes.

Comment: @WebDevBooster so how can I create Bootstrap forms that have a style? As shown above I copied the code from the example but it had no style so I don't really know what to do now to give any Bootstrap 4 components a style without writing stylesheet which sort of obviates the whole point of Bootstrap.

Comment: I think you need to start with the docs and then see how far you get. I mean, it's a very basic form. There isn't much to it. Just a handful of classes to add to replace that custom css.

Comment: @WebDevBooster so Bootstrap requires the developer to manually write styles for all components?

Comment: No, not at all. As I said that particular form was probably created a long time ago and they probably just forgot to update it with native Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be done to make it look the same (almost identical) is to put that form code into a container with an auto-column inside and center the whole thing with the `mx-auto` class and center the content inside with the `text-center` class like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container-fluid bg-light">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto mx-auto my-5 text-center">
            <form class="form-signin">
                <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
                <h1 class="h3 px-5 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
                <div class="checkbox mb-3 mt-2">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also added the `my-5` class to the column to give it a bit more margin on top and bottom. Added the `form-control-lg` classes to the form inputs to make them a bit bigger. And added the `mt-2` (margin-top 2 units) to the checkbox. And `bg-light` was added to the container for background color. That's it. All 100% native Bootstrap classes without any custom css.